# XULRunner not hiding busy indicator on initial startup

Tags: windows, wxwidgets, mozilla, xulrunner

wxWebConnect is a library which enables XULRunner to be embedded and used in wxWidgets applications.  However, when I use it in my application (or in the test application provided with wxWebConnect) on Windows Vista, I find that when I start up my application it shows the spinning busy cursor, and while you keep your mouse over it and don't move it the spinning cursor stays. The instant you move the cursor it drops back to an ordinary pointer cursor. I find this really distracting since I assume there's no point doing anything until the spinning cursor goes away, and so I am still waiting for it to "finish" when in fact it seems there is nothing to finish.  It seems to me it shouldn't stay showing the busy cursor when it is no longer busy.

Does anyone know what might cause this or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a workaround for this problem.

Just use SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_POINTER)) on the main application frame after calling OpenURI() for the first time, and the normal pointer cursor will come up and stay up until the mouse is moved.

It would still be nice to fix it in wxWebConnect code rather than application code, but I think as there have been no answers forthcoming this is the best I will get.